# TEdit Input Validation on C++ Builder XE8

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-xe8

I am very new to C++ Builder XE8.

I want the minimum and maximum length of numbers that must be typed is as much as six numbers, also I need to make sure that only number is entered (0 is exception), and not an alphabetic character, backspace, punctuation, etc.

I would also like to produce an error box if anything other than a number is entered.

I've tried a few combinations of codes, three of which can be seen below, but none of those codes works.

Any help would sure be appreciated!

(1).

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1KeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key)
{
  Edit1->MaxLength = 6;

  if (!((int)Key == 1-9)) {
  ShowMessage("Please enter numerals only");
  Key = 0;
  }
}
```

(2).

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1KeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key)
{
  Edit1->MaxLength = 6;

  if (Key <1 && Key >9) {
  ShowMessage("Please enter numerals only");
  Key = 0;
  }
}
```

(3).

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1KeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key)
{
  Edit1->MaxLength = 6;

  if( Key == VK_BACK )
   return;

  if( (Key >= 1) && (Key <= 9) )
   {
  if(Edit1->Text.Pos(1-9) != 1 )
   ShowMessage("Please enter numerals only");
   Key = 1;
  return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TEdit` has a [`NumbersOnly`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit.NumbersOnly) property:

> Allows only numbers to be typed into the text edit.

Set it to true and let the OS handle the validation for you.  But, if you want to validate it manually, use this:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1KeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key)
{
    // set this at design-time, or at least
    // in the Form's constructor. It does not
    // belong here...
    //Edit1->MaxLength = 6;

    if( Key == VK_BACK )
        return;

    if( (Key < L'0') || (Key > L'9') )
    {
        ShowMessage("Please enter numerals only");
        Key = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate for yoyr help. But, can you please re-read my question above ?, because although your code is works but still there is no prevention to enter the input length of at least 6 numbers

Comment: @Romeo you can't validate the minimum length on the key press event. How would you know if the user is going to keep writing or not? The correct solution is to validate the input value when, for instance, the control loses focus, or when you are ready to use the values (say, a button click). There you can validate the length and contents as you need.

Comment: @Romeo: as I mentioned in the code example, you can still set the `MaxLength` value, just don't do it in the `OnKeyPress` event.

Comment: @RodrigoGómez: you have to be careful if you validate when the Edit loses focus. By the time the `OnExit` event is fired, input focus is already in the process of moving to another window. If you do anything to cause a different window to receive focus, like displaying a popup message, you can really screw up Windows/VCL window management to the point where your UI stops working correctly.  Validating on a button click, for instance, is fine and preferred.

Comment: @Rodrigo: You're right. The aim is to periodically force users to enter the minimum settings length of 6.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `TMaskEdit`: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/idh_useop_textcontrols_xml.html

> TMaskEdit is a special edit control that validates the text entered against a mask that encodes the valid forms the text can take. The mask can also format the text that is displayed to the user.

EDIT: To set a minimum length

```
void __fastcall TForm1::MaskEdit1Exit(TObject *Sender)
{
   if (MaskEdit1->Text.length() < 6)
   {
     //your error message, or throw an exception.
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you provide me a way to enter the input length of at least 6 numbers ?

Comment: @Romeo set the `MaxLength` property to restrict the input to 6 characters. If you want to check for a _minimum_ length, do that in the `OnExit` event. You can do this in either the TEdit or TMaskEdit controls.

Comment: But what I meant is that when entering less than six numbers, then it will produce an error. How to do that in the `OnExit` event?.

Comment: @Romeo have a look at my updated answer. All this is pretty easy to figure out if you read a bit of the documentation.