# TStringGrid Input Validation to permit only numbers, decimals, and commas on C++ Builder XE8

Tags: delphi, c++builder, c++builder-xe8

This question is an extension of another question:

[TEdit Input Validation on C++ Builder XE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800094/tedit-input-validation-on-c-builder-xe8)

I have an editable `TStringGrid`. I only want the user to type numbers and a maximum of one decimal point or comma for each cell in the grid.

From the above link, I understand how to permit only certain keys, but not how to keep track of how many times a certain key-value already exists in the given cell.

From the above link, I have this:

```cpp
void __fastcall TSetDataForm::ProbabilityGridKeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key)
{
    if( Key == VK_BACK )
        return;

    if( (Key < L'0') || (Key > L'9') )
    {
        ShowMessage("Please enter numerals only");
        Key = 0;
    }
}
```

How do I allow `'.'` or `','` but only once?

Comment: What if the input will be e.g. `42.` (`.42` might be acceptable) and the users commits the edit? At that point you cannot predict, I start writing `4`, `2` and `.` but no one can force me to continue writing.

Comment: Otherwise this might do it for dots `if((Key == L'.') && (Edit1->Text.Contains("."))) {ShowMessage("Two dots!"); Key = 0;}`.

Comment: I will be handling those types of issues after the KeyPress event in which it would just read "42." as "42". But if I limit the type of characters (and the number of them) the user inputs, it would significantly reduce the complexity of this post-KeyPress validation. E.g. It would be much more of a pain to deal with something like ".4.2.". In that case I would have no idea what the user wanted. But if it is just "42.", one could assume that the user simply put a useless decimal point.

Comment: @Victoria That looks like it would work but how do I get the text of the specific cell the user is typing in? Since I am dealing with a TStringGrid and not a TEdit.

Comment: `ProbabilityGrid->Cells[ProbabilityGrid->Col][ProbabilityGrid->Row]` might return the text of the cell that is focused.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure it out with that

Comment: @LucaGuarro: Why not use `TryStrToFloat()` to actually parse the cell text to make sure it is a valid decimal value? For example: `if (Key == VK_BACK) return; double value; if (!TryStrToFloat(ProbabilityGrid->Cells[ProbabilityGrid->Col][ProbabilityGrid‌​->Row] + Key, value)) { ShowMessage("Please enter decimal values only"); Key = 0; } }`  You can also use `(Try)StrToFloat()` in your post-validation code, too.

Comment: This approach makes it really hard to the user to work with your control. And in any case, you won't deal with paste from clipboard. Don't validate on key press. Validate later.

Comment: Try doing the validation in the `OnSetEditText` event instead of the `OnKeyPress` event.

Comment: @Remy, if this question is about a grid with `goEditing` option set and this key press event is fired by the inplace edit box, then you cannot form the upcoming text by `CellText + Key` because caret of that edit box can be anywhere. If it's an "Excel like" grid where you simply type (no `goEditing` option), then you cannot validate in the `OnSetEditText` event (because it never fires for such) but when the cell is being left.

Comment: @Victoria: The `CellText + Key` approach will work, as long as you take the edit box selection into account.  I posted an answer that demonstrates this (as well as handling copy/paste).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `TryStrToFloat()` to validate the input, then there is no question whether the user is entering a valid decimal string or not.  You would just need to handle the extra cases where:

- the user is typing a character somewhere other than the end of the edit field, with or without text selected.
- the user is copy/pasting text into the editor.

For example:

```cpp
class TStringGridAccess : public TStringGrid
{
public:
    __property InplaceEditor;
};

void __fastcall TSetDataForm::ProbabilityGridKeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key)
{
    switch (Key)
    {
        case 3: // Ctrl-C
        case 8: // Backspace
            return;

        case 22: // Ctrl-V
        {
            Key = 0;

            TInplaceEdit *Editor = ((TStringGridAccess*)ProbabilityGrid)->InplaceEditor;

            String SaveCellText = ProbabilityGrid->Cells[ProbabilityGrid->Col][ProbabilityGrid->Row];

            String SaveEditText = Editor->Text;
            int SaveSelStart = Editor->SelStart;
            int SaveSelLen = Editor->SelLength;

            Editor->Perform(WM_PASTE, 0, 0);

            TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
            fmt.DecimalSeparator = _D('.');

            double value;
            if (TryStrToFloat(Editor->Text, value, fmt))
                return;

            ProbabilityGrid->Cells[ProbabilityGrid->Col][ProbabilityGrid->Row] = SaveCellText;

            Editor->Text = SaveEditText;
            Editor->SelStart = SaveSelStart;
            Editor->SelLength = SaveSelLen;

            break;
        }

        case _D('0'):
        case _D('1'):
        case _D('2'):
        case _D('3'):
        case _D('4'):
        case _D('5'):
        case _D('6'):
        case _D('7'):
        case _D('8'):
        case _D('9'):
        case _D('.'):
        {
            TInplaceEdit *Editor = ((TStringGridAccess*)ProbabilityGrid)->InplaceEditor;

            String str = Editor->Text;
            int idx = Editor->SelStart;
            int len = Editor->SelLength;

            String str2 = str.SubString(1, idx) + Key + str.SubString(1+idx+len, MaxInt);

            TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
            fmt.DecimalSeparator = _D('.');

            double value;
            if (TryStrToFloat(str2, value, fmt))
                return;

            break;
        }
    }

    ShowMessage(_D("Please enter decimals only"));
    Key = 0;
}
```

Comment: This approach is more sensible than the one I had posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was stemming from the fact that I did not know how to read the text of the cell that the user is writing in.

Here is my solution for anyone interested:

```cpp
void __fastcall TSetDataForm::ProbabilityGridKeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key)
{
    if( Key == VK_BACK )
        return;

    if( !((Key >= L'0') && (Key <= L'9') || (Key == L'.')))
    {
        ShowMessage("Please enter numerals only");
        Key = 0;
    }
    else if ((Key == L'.') &&
        (Pos(Key, ProbabilityGrid->Cells[ProbabilityGrid->Col][ProbabilityGrid->Row]) > 0))
    {
        ShowMessage("Two dots!");
        Key = 0;
    }
}
```